# How to register an open generic decorator for an open generic registration in Autofac?

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have an open generic registration for handlers in autofac that looks like this.

```
  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
     .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This works fine and registers all my handlers for there closed types.  I now want to register a generic decorator for all of the handlers e.g. a

```
LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<>
```

In look from autofac documentation that you need to name your implementation so the decorator can be the default ICommandHandler.  I'm not sure how this works when you are registering open generics. I've tried adding a named to the open registration.

```
  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .Named("commandHandler", typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

And registering the decorator but no joy.

```
 builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof (LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<>), typeof (ICommandHandler<>),
          fromKey: "commandHandler");
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the `autofac` documentation [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html), please try following solution:

```
// Register the open generic with a name so the
// decorator can use it.
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommandHandler<>))
            .Named("commandHandler", typeof(ICommandHandler<>));

// Register the generic decorator so it can wrap
// the resolved named generics.
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
            typeof(LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            fromKey: "commandHandler");
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without giving the concrete type (CommandHandler<>) as a parameter? I.e. so that the registration does not need to change when a new command handler is introduced, as per the original question.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same as you and didnt work; then found solution below.
By [Boby Johnson - Gist](https://gist.github.com/NotMyself/579f94e1aad6a022ddb9)

```
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
           .Where(interfaceType => interfaceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>)))
           .Select(interfaceType => new KeyedService("commandHandler", interfaceType)))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```