# Autofac applying generic decorator on closed types unable to get working

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

Using Autofac 3.5 and MediatR, I am trying to apply a decorator to a closed type that implements a specific interface. I have the following handler type:

```
class ABCQueryHandler: IRequestHandler<GetBankStatementLinesQuery, BankStatementLine>
```

And I would like to apply the following generic open decorator type to all types implementing IRequestHandler<,>:

```
class LoggingHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
```

My Autofac config is:

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)))
        .Select(t => new KeyedService("requestHandler", typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(LoggingHandler<,>), typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), fromKey: "requestHandler")
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The closed type gets injected, but never decorated with the LoggingHandler. I have no idea what I am missing here, tried several approaches as per [How to register an open generic decorator for an open generic registration in Autofac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604014/how-to-register-an-open-generic-decorator-for-an-open-generic-registration-in-au) or [AutoFac - Registering a decorator for some of an open Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088582/autofac-registering-a-decorator-for-some-of-an-open-generic) but none work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing on the open-generic type to the `KeyedService`. You should instead pass on the closed-generic type as follows:

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)))
        .Select(t => new KeyedService("requestHandler", t)))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, this will make it work indeed. I have seen that if you want to use decoratos, you have to register your types differently than when you do not. If you do, use your solution, if you do not, then just use something like: builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();

Comment: Please also note that an [overload of `AsClosedTypesOf` accepting a `serviceKey`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/41044d7d1a4fa277c628021537d5a12016137c3b/src/Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L1021) exists, which takes out having to manually check if the type closes an open-generic interface